# Why is my for loop printing 4 "N" and not looking if the Entry is empty or not?

Tags: python, tkinter

My goals was that the loop goes to the list and sees if the Entry is empty or not. If the Entry is empty it should add to the new list "N" if not it should add "L" but I don't know why it's adding 4 times N

```
class Menu():
    def creat_order(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Bestellung aufgeben")
        root.geometry("450x350")

        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        Button = tk.Button(root, text="Viereck", command=lambda: [root.destroy(), self.Viereck_Menu()])
        Button.config(width=100, height=10, background="red")
        Button.pack()
        # Mainloop

        root.mainloop()

    def Viereck_Menu(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("700x400")
        self.a=tk.StringVar()
        self.b=tk.StringVar()
        self.Umfang=tk.StringVar()
        self.Fleache=tk.StringVar()
        self.Diagonale=tk.StringVar()

        Button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Back", command=lambda: [self.root.destroy(), self.creat_order()])

        # Die ganzen Enterys
        self.E1 = tk.Entry(self.root, font=40, fg="blue", textvariable=self.a)
        self.E1.place(x=170, y=40)
        self.E2 = tk.Entry(self.root, font=40, fg="blue")
        self.E2.place(x=170, y=70)
        self.E3 = tk.Entry(self.root, font=40, fg="blue")
        self.E3.place(x=170, y=100)
        self.E4 = tk.Entry(self.root, font=40, fg="blue")
        self.E4.place(x=170, y=130)
        self.E5 = tk.Entry(self.root, font=40, fg="blue")
        self.E5.place(x=170, y=160)
        self.LabelforPicture = tk.Label(self.root)
        self.LabelforPicture.place(x=400, y=65)
        self.Button = tk.Button(text="Berechnen", command=lambda: self.New_list())
        self.Button.pack()
    def New_list(self):
        self.get2 = [self.a.get(), self.b.get(), self.Umfang.get(), self.Fleache.get(), self.Diagonale.get()]
        self.new = []
        for i in range(len(self.get2)):
            if self.get2[i] == "":
                self.new.append("N")
            else:
                self.new.append("L")

        print(self.new)
```

I was expecting that the for loop goes to the list and sees in the Entries which one is empty and which not. If one Entry would be empty it should add the letter N to a new list and so on... but it's adding 4 "N"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: If you're getting 4 N, that means that 4 of the entries are empty.

Comment: do you mean ?   for i in self.get2:
            if i == "":
                self.new.append("N")
            else:
                self.new.append("L")
        print(self.new)
 when yea it sadly did not work...

Comment: Part of the problem likely stems from creating more than one root window. You should only create a single instance of `Tk`. If you need more windows, use `Toplevel`.

Comment: but how can this be? if i do if with just self.a.get() it usually works but it do not work with the list

Comment: its ok i know what the problem was ..... i fixed it thx guys!

Comment: There's no need to use `self.variable` for values that are only needed within a single function. `self` is used for saving state across functions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `StringVar()`

Change this:

```
for entry in [self.E1, self.E2, self.E3, self.E4, self.E5]:
```

to:

```
self.get2 = [self.E1.get(), self.E2.get(), self.E3.get(), self.E4.get(), self.E5.get()]
```

Screenshot You can see debug:

[image]